# Get rowspan and cospan of Word document table

Tags: c#, vsto, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to get the colspan and rowspan value of the table in wordprocessingML.

Can anyone explain how I can get these two values using openXML?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution,

```
private static int CalcColspan(XElement cell)
            {
                if (cell.Name != W.tc)
                    return 0;
                return cell.Element(W.tcPr).Element(W.gridSpan) == null ? 1 :
                        Convert.ToInt32(cell.Element(W.tcPr).Element(W.gridSpan).Attribute(W.val).Value);
            }

private static int CalcRowspan(XElement cell)
            {
                if (cell.Name != W.tc)
                    return 0;
                int rowspan = 1, colNum = 0;
                XElement currentRow = cell.Parent;
                foreach (XElement tc in cell.NodesBeforeSelf())
                {
                    colNum += CalcColspan(tc);
                }
                bool endOfSpan = false;
                foreach (XElement row in currentRow.NodesAfterSelf())
                {
                    int currentColNum = 0;
                    foreach (XElement tc in row.Nodes())
                    {
                        if (tc.Name != W.tc)
                            continue;
                        if (currentColNum == colNum)
                        {
                            if (tc.Element(W.tcPr).Element(W.vMerge) != null)
                            {
                                if ((string)tc.Element(W.tcPr).Element(W.vMerge).Attribute(W.val) != "restart")
                                {
                                    rowspan++;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            endOfSpan = true;
                        }
                        currentColNum += CalcColspan(tc);
                    }
                    if (endOfSpan)
                        break;
                }
                return rowspan;
            }
```